# Can't run sox, No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, sox

In Ubuntu 12.04 I installed sox with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install sox
```

Now if I use this command:

```
sox message.wav message.flac rate 16k
```

I get this:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/sox: No such file or directory
```

If I use this command:

```
sox --version
```

I get this:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/sox: No such file or directory
```

But if I use this command:

```
which sox
```

I get this:

```
/usr/bin/sox
```

So now what do I have to do in order to convert WAV to FLAC using sox?

Comment: Your usage seems to be correct, the real question is why you can't run sox.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your shell has cached the location of `sox` for some reason.  You can work around the problem by giving the full path of the command:

```
/usr/bin/sox message.wav message.flac rate 16k
```

Try `hash -r` to clear your shell's command cache.  Also try `alias | grep sox` in case you have an alias set to a bad location.

Comment: The problem got solved with a restart.But now I am getting this:
john@john-System-Product-Name:~$ sox message.wav message.flac rate 16k
sox WARN wav: Premature EOF on .wav input file
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 4355 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN sox: `message.flac' output clipped 2309 samples; decrease volume?
The conversion is getting done though.